# What is the easiest way to get ZedGraph to use scientific notation instead of engineering notation?

Tags: c#, .net, zedgraph

ZedGraph likes to use engineering notation for its axes, e.g. 300*10^3 instead of scientific notation, e.g. 3*10^5. What is the easiest way to change this?

Comment: Can you clarify, how does 300*10^3 == 3*10^5?

Comment: 300E3 == 3E5, is that clearer? [Engineering notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_notation) only uses powers of 10 in multiples of 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out an automatic way to do this, but it's only one line of code to do it manually:

```
zedGraph1.GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.Mag = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(zedGraph1.GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.Max));
```